# BigQuery - BATCH mode queries randomly failing with resources exceeded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

A part of our application submits 100s of BQ queries to build an aggregated dashboard view. Due to the large number of queries, we submit all queries with BATCH priority.

In last 24 hours we've had quite a few queries (more than 300) fail due to resources exceeded. This is odd as some of the failed queries save results to an output table specifically to avoid this type of issue. We spot checked a few others and are able to run them without issue in the BQ web UI.

Sample job ID (no dest table): job_GPghMyEBvlYFBGBHI5Szv0HMIpMY

Query:

```
SELECT order_sub.value as value, count(*) as count
FROM
(
  SELECT order_id, drop_ship as value
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY(d34f20170905T212849Zc4abca, 'table_id IN ("order_detail_2018")'))
  WHERE order_date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2018-01-01") AND TIMESTAMP("2018-08-31")
) order_sub
JOIN EACH
(
  SELECT customer_id, order_id, sequence
  FROM temp_30_days.query_q6109c34f20180918T151206Ze52003_buyers
) cust_sub
ON order_sub.order_id = cust_sub.order_id
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY value
```

Error Message:

```
"status": {
  "state": "DONE",
  "errorResult": {
    "reason": "resourcesExceeded",
    "message": "Resources exceeded during query execution."
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "reason": "resourcesExceeded",
      "message": "Resources exceeded during query execution."
    }
  ]
}
```

Sample job ID (with dest table): job_2YsCt-cxql5TP0jklb1aRENzINdZ

Query:

```
SELECT
  customer_id, sequence
FROM
(
  SELECT
    customer_id,
    sequence,
    random,
    MAX(random) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) AS max_value
  FROM
  (
    SELECT customer_id, sequence, RAND() as random
    FROM (TABLE_QUERY(d34f20170905T212849Zc4abca, 'table_id IN ("cust_char_2015", "cust_char_2016", "cust_char_2017")'))
    WHERE end_date >= TIMESTAMP("2016-12-31")
    AND effective_date <= TIMESTAMP ("2017-08-31")
    AND (frequency_end = "98")
  )
)
WHERE max_value = random
GROUP EACH BY
  customer_id, sequence
```

Error Message:

```
"status": {
  "errorResult": {
    "message": "Resources exceeded during query execution.", 
    "reason": "resourcesExceeded"
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Resources exceeded during query execution.",
      "reason": "resourcesExceeded"
    }
  ],
  "state": "DONE"
}
```

FWIW [status.cloud.google.com](http://status.cloud.google.com/) shows green lights for BigQuery, is anyone else experiencing similar issues?

Comment: Please update your question with the query that is causing this error and the complete error message.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard couple other items to note: during our batch runs, the same queries did NOT fail every time, which is what we looked at first. We were able to successfully execute all queries by resubmitting and setting priority = INTERACTIVE.

Comment: Have you tried using standard SQL instead? You're less likely to hit problems with scaling `GROUP BY` and `PARTITION BY`. With that said, it's not clear to me what the purpose of `MAX(random)` is. It looks like you could just be using `ANY_VALUE`, for instance.

Comment: It doesn't appear Standard vs Legacy is the issue (or using MAX vs ANY_VALUE we can start a separate thread for a code review if you'd like) - I can give you a standard sql Job ID that failed as well. We've been running these same batches of queries monthly with batch priority without issue for over a year. Just seems odd that things started failing randomly yesterday

Comment: It could be that the queries were close to the limit previously, and some small change in the data is now causing them to fail, for example. You could [file a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with a project/job ID for one of the failures to ask someone from the BigQuery team to take a look.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I will file an issue, thanks for the issue tracker link!

Comment: I would start by removing EACH keyword from both queries. As documentation says, "EACH used to be encouraged in many cases, but this is no longer the case." These days JOIN and GROUP BY uses multiple partitions in both cases, but without EACH BigQuery uses newer mechanisms to define these partitions.

Comment: @Michael both examples above are using Legacy SQL (we are in the process of re-writing all queries in Standard SQL) but as I mentioned above - Legacy vs Standard does NOT appear to be the issue. I can submit either query above in the BQ UI w/ out issue and via API if we set priority to INTERACTIVE. FWIW - BQUI says first query processes a whopping 18.1 MB; the second 805 MB, which is quite a bit more than the first, but still peanuts for BQ.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard just following up on this as you had suggested filing an issue and it paid off. It turns out limit hit in this case is a per project total number of in-flight shuffle bytes (was totally unaware of this limit). As the engineer points out in the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/116075441): "The jobs you've listed may just be innocent bystanders -- the jobs that happened to push you over the limit" I've identified the main offender and think I have a workaround. Thx for your assistance w/ this.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that it worked out!